# Iterating through a $_session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have created a session array as follows

```
$_SESSION['memberInfo']['memberFirstName'] = ($first_name);
$_SESSION['memberInfo']['memberLastName'] = ($surname);
$_SESSION['memberInfo']['hash'] = ($hash);
$_SESSION['memberInfo']['templateSrc'] = ($newTemplateSrc);
```

in other pages where I'm trying to get the values from the array I have tried foreach and while loops without success, I can see the array in a var_dump

```
var_dump($_SESSION['memberInfo']);
```

which shows in console as

```
array(4) {
  ["memberFirstName"]=>
  string(8) "Geoffrey"
  ["memberLastName"]=>
  string(6) "Turner"
  ["hash"]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$YBE1tc.BK7yq6bBr/JAlWuN0H8xGdoNSAWzU4/zfd1r3v7jprNBD2"
  ["templateSrc"]=>
  string(61) "../userDirectory/558386500/html/Geoffrey_Turner_558386500.php"
}
```

in the pages where im trying to itterate the array I have tried using

```
foreach ($_SESSION['memberInfo'] as $name)
{
$first_name = $name['memberFirstName'];
}
```

the responce I get shows as

Warning: Illegal string offset 'memberFirstName'

which I believe suggests the itteration is reading an empty array

I can echo out the array using

```
foreach ($_SESSION['memberInfo'] as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

which results in

```
memberFirstName = Geoffrey
memberLastName = Turner
hash = $2y$10$YBE1tc.BK7yq6bBr/JAlWuN0H8xGdoNSAWzU4/zfd1r3v7jprNBD2
templateSrc = ../userDirectory/558386500/html/Geoffrey_Turner_558386500.php
```

but for the life of me I cannot seem to figure out how to get each of the array values individually and assign them to a variable

Comment: The variable `$_SESSION['memberInfo']` is an array as you show with the `var_dump`. The `foreach` will iterate down that array as normal. You ask to the 'value' side of the array but called it `$name`. To get the $name and $value you need to do: _`$_SESSION['memberInfo'] as $name => $value`_.

Comment: @ Ryan Vincent I did try that as in the  echo I could see the pairs using the $key => $value, I just didnt know how to get them induvidually and assign to a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreach makes no sense as you looping an trying to assing single variable too many times for no benefits. So this to be removed:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['memberInfo'] as $name =) {
    $first_name = $name['memberFirstName'];
}
```

as all you need is:

```
$first_name = $_SESSION['memberInfo']['memberFirstName'];
```

Answer (score 2):

> how to get each of the array values individually and assign them to a variable

You can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) which extracts each value and assigns it to a variable.

`extract($_SESSION['memberInfo'])` this should create the following variables

`$memberFirstName`, `$memberLastName`, `$hash`, `$templateSrc`

Here is a demo **http://ideone.com/XYpC7n**

Comment: While technically correct, this is rather bad approach because suddenly you get bunch of new variables "out of nowhere". Taking data from array directly is safer and code is clearer.

Comment: It works, although like it has been mentioned it's as if the created variables are in the ether so to speak

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, You are right. However, I still suggested this approach as an answer after noticing that OP maintains an array in the session under `memberInfo`. So I assume the data that goes into `memberInfo` is expected.